# "Periodicity" of the Wiener integral?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be the standard Brownian motion.
I am thinking about "translation" in Wiener integral.  For exemple we have, for a non random constant $c$,$s,t\in \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{s}^{t+s} c\cdot dB_u=c(B(t+s)-B(s))\overset{d}=cB(t)=\int_0^tc\cdot dB_u$$ from stationarity of the increments.

What's happen if we take, more generally a $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (non-random) function $f$ ?

> Do we have that for any $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}),(s,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $$\int_{s}^{t+s} f(u)dB_u\overset{d}=\int_0^t f(u+s)B_u.$$

Obviously the method is to prove it first for step functions of the form $f=\sum a_i \bf{1}_{(\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1})}$ but I have to be careful because I would have a sum, so I cannot do everything I want.

I suppose that the result is true.

Comment: Do you mean to have $f(u+s)$ on the right side of the equation in your question?  As the equation stands it's trivially false.

Comment: Otherwise, can you explain in more detail what you tried and where you got stuck?  You say "I cannot do everything that I want" - can you clarify what you want to do and why you don't think you can justify it?

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry for the delay, I had some problems. I mean that if I start with a step function I would have $\sum a_i (B(t_i)-B(t_{i+1}))$. But I don't have, in general $X\sim Y,U\sim V$ (with independance)  implies $X+U\sim Y+V$ where $\sim$ is the equality in distribution. Even the formal change of variables $u'+s=u$ leads to (for the LHS) $\int_0^t f(u'+s)dB_{u'+s}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest way to see this is to note that
$$
\int_s^{t+s} f(u)\,dB_u\sim N\left(0,\int_{s}^{t+s}f(u)^2\,du\right)=N\left(0,\int_{0}^{t}f(u+s)^2\,du\right)\sim \int_0^{t} f(u+s)\,dB_u,
$$
provided that $f$ is deterministic. If $f$ is merely predictable, then you need to go back to the Riemann sums.